Is the word "you" used as generic "you" here?
In Barbie (2023), Barbie creator Ruth's ghost speaks to Barbie:

Ruth: Humans make things up like patriarchy and Barbie just to deal
with how uncomfortable it is.
Barbie: I understand that.
Ruth: And then you die.

Is the word "you" used as generic "you" here?

"how uncomfortable [life] is" is just another way of saying Life's a bitch .... and then you die.

... I'm doubtful whether the multilayered cultural allusions and wordplay in Barbie would make suitable source material for non-Anglophones wanting to learn the basic language. But people gotta make up their own minds, I guess. Not to give away any spoilers, but Barbie's final line makes it clear this isn't a movie aimed at children!

@FumbleFingers I suggest you take a look at this OP's questions...

What do you think I've just done? (Don't answer that! :)

@FumbleFingers - I once saw a cartoon in some magazine (it was the 1970s) which depicted two turtles contemplating a vast expanse of sand and one says to the other 'and then you die'.

Dear OP... is your name really 'Cameron Melvin'?

@MichaelHarvey: I think the two guys buried up to their necks in sand under the desert sun (one saying to the other, "Okay, what's the plan?") is a bit later. Same basic idea, though. Oh, just remembered - there's a herd of stampeding wildebeest bearing down on them!

@FumbleFingers - When it came in the UK the media were full of stories about women who had arranged to go in groups, in themed clothing, with children (likewise), to see the movie, only to, in many cases, have to leave half way through because their six year olds were bored or freaked out.

@FumbleFingers - I love cartoons. I spend half my time copying them from the New Yorker onto my Facebook page. I had a lovely book of French cartoons with translated captions once in which was one with the classic 'desert island' (about 10 feet wide, with one palm tree) and on it, a single shaggy-haired, bearded man, who has somehow managed to cover his eyes, from behind, with his own hands, and he's saying 'Guess who?'.

@MichaelHarvey: Re inappropriate kids in the audience, see this comment under yet another Barbie question. Laugh? I nearly shat!

The conversation at that point: "That Ken of yours, he is one nice-looking little protein pot" ... "I guess" ... "I'd like to see what kind of nude blob he's packing under those jeans!"

@FumbleFingers - that link just leads to your SE profile page.

@MichaelHarvey: Oops. Clumsy mouse selection. Here's the right link.

@FumbleFingers - I agree with your assessment. An Irish Independent column had something to say about this kind of stuff. Linking sexual attractiveness to being nice to eat is not a new thing - consider people being called 'dishes'.

It's somewhat ambiguous. Ruth is a ghost who, as a living human, made up Barbie and then died. So she is talking about herself.
But she's also talking about humanity as a whole. The things that humans do because life is difficult and senseless. So she is talking in general.
That's part of the joke. Barbie contains quite a few multi-layered jokes and observations.

Ruth Marianna Handler was alive until 2002, so she'd probably have been familiar with Life's a bitch and then you die - which as that The Dictionary of Modern Proverbs link says, originated in the early 1980s. But ghosts aside, I'm sure the scriptwriters intended the reference.

If I may paraphrase your question:

When Ruth says "And then you die" does she mean people in general or Barbie in particular?

The answer is "both", but mostly Barbie in particular. It can be taken ambiguously, and it is ambiguous grammatically, but context makes it clear she means Barbie; mostly.
First, she's talking about "people in general" in the first sentence and so the second sentence is talking about people in general too. It's an echo of "Life's a bitch and then you die.", which does mean people in general. But also the whole speech is in the context of Barbie wanting  to be human and what Ruth says is a clear warning that if she does that then she, Barbie, will in fact have to die. She says it at several other places in the scene.

I think there's a limit to how far you can take this "literal meaning" business. Brilliant as Margot Robbie is, she can't overcome the ground truth - as a doll, Barbie never was and never will be "alive".

The whole conversation is specifically about becoming human. The point of it is that if Barbie becomes human then she will die. If she stays as a doll, then she won't have to; but if she becomes human then she will.
